# Get FormView From Its InsertItemTemplate Child Button

Tags: asp.net, formview

I have a FormView on my WebPage and I am trying to get the FormView when my Submit button is pressed inside the FormView's InsertItemTemplate. How can I do that. My sender of the event is the button but not the FormView. Is there any property for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access FV directly via it's ID in the ButtonClick.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string id = FormView1.ID;
        //Here is an explicit way to do get FV
        //FormView fv = (FormView)((Button)sender).NamingContainer;
}
```

Comment: Actually the FormView is inside the Repeater.

Comment: Did you try the second method i.e. NamingContainer one??